# Map a specific Web App Service Path to a Custom Domain

Tags: azure, dns, mapping

I am looking for a way in Azure to map Web App Service paths to domain names I own.

For example

Map xyz.com to .azurewebsites.net/Views?id=xyz

Map abc.com to .azurewebsites.net/Views?id=abc

Is this possible ?

I know I can map xyz.com to .azurewebsites.net and use the custom domain feature to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, just not with straight DNS. Easiest way in Azure to do this, in my opinion is to create a Front Door - which is a really easy-to-configure and fully-featured HTTP load balancer (note I call out HTTP here, as this is the level on which Front Door works - if you need lower-level protocol support you'll need another solution).

Front Door allows you to register custom domains ("front end") addresses and then map them to different web apps ("back end services") using routing rules. Those routing rules allow you to either forward (which would act similarly to a reverse proxy) or redirect to your desired path.